# Help with $\int_{0}^{T} I_{0}(2\sqrt{ y x})\cos(tx)dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

i am trying to do the integral :

$$\int_{0}^{T} I_{0}(2\sqrt{ y x})\cos(tx)dx$$

Where $I_{0}(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function if the first kind of the zeroth order.

Comment: And so? What are your attempts?

Comment: i don't have the first clue !

Comment: At least, where this problem arises? For finite $T$ I do not expect a nice closed form for the integral, but $I_0$ has a nice Laplace transform, so you may try to exploit that.

Comment: It arises in the calculation of a smooth part of a counting function. for $T\rightarrow \infty$ the integral diverges ! i hope that a counter part can absorb the divergence.

Comment: The integral as a function of $T$ has wild oscillations since $I_0(x)$ grows like $e^x$ for large $x$, so we expect that the integral $\int_{0}^{T}I_0(x)\cos(x)\,dx$ behaves roughly like $\pm e^T$ with the sign depending on the parity of $\lfloor T/\pi\rfloor$. I doubt that this may be the smooth part of a counting function.

Comment: it is not ... it arose during the calculation of that counting function. btw, i looked at your profile, and it says you work in analytic number theory, which is the topic of my current research. how can i send you a draft of my paper !? because i am stuck, and need help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24834/discussion-between-mohammad-al-jamal-and-jack-daurizio).